# Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, exception, twilio

I am using the `JDK 1.8` and `Twilio 8.17.0` and `HttpClient 4.5.12` and I am still experiencing the same issue. Please help me.

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.([Ljava/lang/String;)V

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Javadoc for that constructor ([https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRedirectStrategy.html#DefaultRedirectStrategy(java.lang.String[])](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRedirectStrategy.html#DefaultRedirectStrategy(java.lang.String%5B%5D))) it says `Since 4.5.10`.

While you compiled against 4.5.12, I suspect that you are running with a different version.